# Showing D Coverage Results as Overlays in Source Buffer

Tags: emacs, code-coverage, d, readonly, dmd

The D language compiler DMD outputs its coverage analysis in a file containing the original source as

`|    inout(Ix)[] prefix() inout
         |    {
     2037|        assert(!keys.empty);
     2037|        final switch (keys.length)
         |        {
000000000|        case 1:
000000000|            return keys.at!0[];
     2037|        case 2:
         |            import std.algorithm.searching : commonPrefix;
     2037|            return commonPrefix(keys.at!0[], keys.at!1[]);
         |        }
         |    }`

that is, the original source where each line has been prefixed by a 10-character column containing the execution count (if relevant).

When opened in Emacs I would like this file to be presented as a read-only version of the original source buffer with an green overlay for the lines exercised at least once and with red overlay for the lines never exercised.

How is this most conveniently implemented in Emacs-Lisp? For instance is there a way to efficiently hide the first 10 characters of each line in a buffer?

See also: https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1074

Comment: How about using the fringe for the vertical line (its width and color can be adjusted) and using your own numbers and so forth to the left of the fringe, similar to `linum-mode`?  They are overlays with the `before-string` property and a window margin.  There is no need to truncate/hide portions of the text unless of course you want to.  The whole thing, however, looks like it doesn't neatly fit into an answer -- i.e., it requires time to write and debug.

Comment: Before writing up an example of how to merely hide the first 10 characters of each line, it appears you need to give some more thought (perhaps with the forum participants giving input) as to the overall design of what your `elisp` code will do when fully implemented.

Comment: Extended `flycheck-d-unittest` with coverage support and put it up at https://github.com/nordlow/elisp/blob/master/mine/flycheck-d-all.el