# Most efficient way of collecting numbers in the first n columns of a buffer

Tags: performance, search, emacs, buffer, elisp

If I have a buffer containing

```
         |    inout(Ix)[] prefix() inout
         |    {
     2037|        assert(!keys.empty);
     2037|        final switch (keys.length)
         |        {
000000000|        case 1:
000000000|            return keys.at!0[];
     2037|        case 2:
         |            import std.algorithm.searching : commonPrefix;
     2037|            return commonPrefix(keys.at!0[], keys.at!1[]);
         |        }
         |    }
```

what's the most efficient way of iterating over all lines that have a number to the left of the pipe-character?

Is `re-search-forward` together with `match-string` the most efficient way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chose to add line-numbers to the result because there is another related thread -- [Showing D Coverage Results as Overlays in Source Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418669/showing-d-coverage-results-as-overlays-in-source-buffer) -- that indicates the original poster would like to place overlays and so forth using the result.  [The original poster may wish to add a little bit more stuff to the result (e.g., such as `point` locations in the buffer), and then take the result and `mapc` down that list -- placing overlays with the `before-string` property inside the left margin (before the left fringe) if so desired.  The text of each line from the far-left to the pipe can also be deleted (or hidden), so that the overlays take the place of what has been deleted (or hidden).]

```lisp
(let (result)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while (re-search-backward "^\s?+\\([0-9]?+\\)|" nil t)
      (push (cons (format-mode-line "%l") (match-string 1)) result))
    result))
```

The result looks like this:

`(("1" . "") ("2" . "") ("3" . "2037") ("4" . "2037") ("5" . "") ("6" . "000000000") ("7" . "000000000") ("8" . "2037") ("9" . "") ("10" . "2037") ("11" . "") ("12" . ""))`

Comment: I chose `re-search-backward` together with `match-string`. Here's my solution: https://github.com/nordlow/elisp/blob/master/mine/flycheck-d-all.el#L70 Thanks.

Comment: I like `^\\(.........\\)` as it relates to each `.` capturing a character (e.g., nine dots, equals 9 characters) -- thank you for sharing your regexp.  :)

Answer (score 2):

What you propose is fast already.

If you're really desperate for speed, you can avoid regular expressions and `search-forward` newline and pipe. Then call `string-to-number`. Is it worth the effort ?

Answer (score 0):

`skip-chars-forward` is faster than `search-forward`.

However, that is true only, if the task is done with it. If a repeat is needed, things already are different. `search-forward` is a much more comfortable function.
While it's possible to write `(while (search-forward "MY-CHAR"))`, `skip-chars-forward` stops at the match, thus requiring an additional `forward-char`. Roughly spoken with such an additional Emacs-Lisp level to employ, the speed-advantage of `skip-chars-forward` is egalized. As quite often check for EOB is needed, which `search-forward` has built-in, `skip-chars-forward` loses soon.

If a single char is searched once, `skip-chars-forward` might be an option.

IMO it would require a benchmark to know if the form below is faster than a resp. one using `re-search-forward`:

```
(defun stop-at-numbers-in-this-special-case ()
  (interactive)
  (while
      (and (skip-chars-forward "^|")
       (eq (char-before) 32))
    (forward-char 1)))
```

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispBenchmark